# Mysql store blob on other table for increase speed of alter table

Tags: mysql, blob, alter

With MySQL, what is the best way to build a table with one million rows and many fields TEXT and varchar(200 to 2000) ?

Is it better to add a one to one relationship table with all of big fields and store varchar(2000) in TEXT ?

And what is the impact of alter table on the first table on the second one ?

Comment: Could you give us some more specific information about what will be stored in the tables?

Comment: And I don't think a one to one relationship is useful. In fact, it would cause performance overheads to the database engine for having to link the table rows together.

Comment: Actually an alter table take approximately 10 minutes when we change an existing field or add one. I think, if I decrease size of table it will takes less time doesn't it ?

Comment: But then you have to update two table's, isn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily, for an update and very rarely for an alter table.

Comment: I think this would be up for a good test! Just make a test bd and take a look if it ís faster.